# How to make binding in Laravel that depends on class and method

Tags: laravel, binding, service-provider

I look for the way to make simple binding in Laravel. This binding must depend on class and method that I am using.

That is my User Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function getIndex(SomeClass $someClass) {
        return $someClass->action();
    }
}
```

That is my SomeClass:

```
class SomeClass {
    private $number;
    public function __construct(int $number) {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function action() {
        return "Lorem ipsum ". $this->number;
    }
}
```

I want to make in one binding that will follow the condition
When I use UserController and its the method getIndex then I want to call SomeClass with given param (and the key is that the given param I want to define in that binding.

I tried below example, but it does not work the way I need:

```
$this->app->when(UserController::class)
          ->needs(SomeClass::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new SomeClass(4434);
          });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)? This uses the route variable name to resolve a specific model